# kafka ingestion with cloudera and IBM MQ

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-mq, cloudera, apache-kafka-connect

Is it possible to capture IBM MQ data with Kafka-Cloudera?

The confluent company offers connectors to capture IBM MQ data, but I'm not sure if I can do the same with Kafka-Cloudera.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Kafka Connect is not a framework specific to Confluent or Cloudera. It is built into all Apache Kafka offerings.

If Confluent Platform includes a specific connector as part of the OSS offering, for which you can individually download and use the connector, then that's a separate issue.